# Which benchers have the harachaman for the state of Israel?

Tags: product-recommendation, bentching, state-of-israel

Which benchers include the line: "harachaman hu yivareich et medinat yisrael, reishit tzmichat geulateinu"?

Which include a harachaman for chayalei Tzahal or for peace between bnei Sarah and bnei Hagar?

Comment: http://www.korenpub.com/EN/products/holiday/holiday/9789653012721 ?

Comment: Edited to be more clear and specific in line with guidelines

Comment: I've seen both Sarah/Hagar and Yishmael/Yizhak.  Do you not want to know about the second?

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen the latter.

Comment: These lines appear (with variations) in Reform Zionist youth movements' versions of _Birkat ha-Mazon_. See in PDF downloadable [here](http://www.rsy-netzer.org.uk/resources/download-document/15-birkat-hamazon.html) (on second page), and listed in differences from the traditional _Birkat ha-Mazon_ in PDF [here](http://noartelem.org.il/sites/default/files/training-center/ברכת%20המזון.pdf). The former has the Sarah/Hagar version, and the latter mentions the Yishmael/Yizhak one. They differ from the traditional _Birkat ha-Mazon_ in more significant ways, as well.

Answer (score 3):

The beautiful (in my opinion) [Koren Birkon](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/products/holiday/holiday/9789653012721) contains the "*Harachaman*"s for both the State of Israel and the Israeli Defense Forces. Here's a photo of the page that has them:

[image: Snapshot from the Koren Birkon]

Comment: You mean [Birkon Koren](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/enlarge.php?pdId=478)?

Comment: Just being pedantic about syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with printing benchers for occasions is that there are printers that customize the content for not very much money per bencher. So take a bencher that you kept from an occation that has a reasonably close Nusach to what you want (e.g. Ashkenaz, etc.) call the number printed on it, and ask them. If they don't do that level of customization, it is quite likely they know someone who does.